Kubuntu 24.04 no output or input devices found
Fresh install the sound worked perfect on Kubuntu 22.04
my Laptop is pretty old HP Spectre x360 13t
I think I need to downgrade some drivers https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494753 but I don't know

Any help will be greatly welcomed

I've gotten this on Kubuntu 23.10 a couple of times, including right now. Would love a solution other than rebooting.
